# testing nested component callback in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, reactjs-testutils

given a `Foo` (root) component that renders `Baz` nested component, where `Baz` has a property named `onOperationDone` which accepts a callback.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onOperationDone = () => {
      console.log("do something");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Baz onOperationDone={this.onOperationDone} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

what are the steps that needs to be done to make `Baz` to execute the callback in order to make sure the callback is being invoked (using [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) or [test-utils](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html))?

could you please help me understand how it should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things seem a bit weird to me in your code. I'm assuming they are typos when creating the question but I will comment on them nonetheless. If what I'm assuming happens to be wrong, say so and I will edit my answer accordingly.

First of all, your render method is not returning anything. Typically, the JSX should be placed inside a return statement.

Secondly, the `onOperationDone` method is declared inside the constructor the class. That means every time you create a new instance of the class the method is also created (taking the necessary amount of memory). Instead, I would define the method in the prototype of the class, so it is shared between all instances.

With that in mind, your class would look like (note that I have deleted the constructor since it would only be calling the `super` and that is done automatically):

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    onOperationDone() {
        console.log("do something");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Baz onOperationDone={this.onOperationDone} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, to test that when the `Baz` component calls the `onOperationDone` property the `onOperationDone` method of `Foo` is called, I would set an spy on the `Foo` `onOperationDone` method to check that it is called. Then, I would search for the `Baz` element and call its `onOperationDone`.

With enzyme, you can do:

```
it('the child calls its parent callback', function() {
    jest.spyOn(Foo.prototype, 'onOperationDone');

    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
    wrapper.find(Baz).prop('onOperationDone')();
    expect(Foo.prototype.onOperationDone).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

### Spying methods of the class instances

If you are trying to spy a method that belongs to the instances of your class (whether it is by defining the method in the constructor, as in your case, or by using [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)), the thing gets a bit trickier.

Let's say you are trying to spy the `onOperationDone` in your initial code:

```
export default class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onOperationDone = () => {
            console.log("do something");
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Baz onOperationDone={this.onOperationDone} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If you try the same approach from spying the `prototype` but spying instead the instance method, it will not work:

```
it('the child calls its parent callback', function() {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'onOperationDone');

    wrapper.find(Baz).prop('onOperationDone')();
    expect(instance.onOperationDone).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

It will fail stating that the spied method was not called (although you will see the log "do something").

This is because when you shallow render the `Foo` component, a new `onOperationDone` method is being created and added to the instance, and then the render method is called and the `onOperationDone` is being assigned as a prop to the `Baz` component.

Next, you are spying the instance method (with `jest.spyOn`) but what this does is that it creates a new method that wraps your original `onOperationDone` in order to track the number of times it has been called and other statistics. The thing is, that the `Baz` prop has not changed, and it is a reference to the original method, not the wrapped one. So the wrapped method never gets called.

To overcome this, we need to force an update of the component (so that the wrapped `onOperationDone` gets assigned as prop of `Baz` component. To do that we have the [update](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) method of enzyme's shallow renderer. Unfortunately, it seems that the update method does not always [force a re-render](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2042).

So a workaround is to call the [setProps](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.html) method to force the update. The final test code should look like:

```
it('the child calls its parent callback', function() {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ChildComponentCallbackInstance />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'onOperationDone');

    // wrapper.update(); would be the ideal method to call
    wrapper.setProps({});

    wrapper.find(Baz).prop('onOperationDone')();
    expect(instance.onOperationDone).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: **thank you for the detailed explanation!** i've changed my snippet to include the `return` statement (it was left out when i stipped off the code). could you please also elaborate how can the same be done when the `onOperationDone` is defined within the constructor (as in my snippet)? `onOperationDone` modifies the state and i would like to avoid using `bind()` when `onOperationDone` is passed to `Baz`)

Comment: @Mr., I updated the answer to take into account the case you want to test. Hope it helps!

Comment: sorry, could you provide example with functional component? please